# Using a comma to separate these clauses?

Tags: grammar, american-english, commas, clauses

English is my second language. A co-worker who edits my work wrote the following two phrases:

> This way, workers can install the guardrail for the next level from a lower platform eliminating the need for a fall arrest system during assembly.
>
> Thanks to this method, it is not necessary to use a personal fall arrest system during any stage in working with the system making it easier to work safely.

Is it me, or do both of these phrases need an extra comma?

> This way, workers can install the guardrail for the next level from a lower ***platform,*** eliminating the need for a fall arrest system during assembly.
>
> Thanks to this method, it is not necessary to use a personal fall arrest system during any stage in working with the ***system,*** making it easier to work safely.

Can someone please help me verify this, I've been Googling this but I haven't been able to find the rule here...

Comment: It appears that the last one would be the correct structure.

Comment: Your way is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: it is better to add a comma between a clause and a non-defining participial phrase, i.e. a participial phrase providing some extra information (rather than limiting what the noun refers to, as my participle "providing" does here). I'm not sure I'd call that comma compulsory, but it is certainly a great improvement